# How do I change a TCP socket to be non-blocking?

Tags: c, sockets

How do you make a socket non-blocking?

I am aware of the `fcntl()` function, but I've heard it's not always reliable.

Comment: It's only unreliable if you're not doing error checking and assuming it's always succeeding. :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What do you mean by "not always reliable"? If the system succeeds in setting your socket non non-blocking, it will be non-blocking. Socket operations will return `EWOULDBLOCK` if they would block need to block (e.g. if the output buffer is full and you're calling send/write too often).

[This forum thread](http://developerweb.net/viewtopic.php?id=3000) has a few good points when working with non-blocking calls.

Comment: I don't think this is a good answer.  You tell him that it should be reliable then post a forum thread that can become quickly out of date.  Just my opinion, but someone with your rep I would have thought would be thoughtful enough to provide a more thorough answer than a lazy link and quick comment.

Comment: @Matt Sorry to disappoint. Please note that this answer is four and a half years old. I think my answer reveals my frustration with the question's lack of detail. It's hard to argument with "I've heard that doing it the obvious way is not always reliable". I still think so, not sure how to improve on this.

Comment: Yeah I realised later just how old the question was.  Thinking it was new because someone else updated it and it came up in the activity list... oops.  never mind.

Comment: Note from the manpages: "POSIX.1-2001 allows either error [EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK] to be returned for this  case, and does not require these constants to have the same value, so a portable application should check for both possibilities."

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 109):

[`fcntl()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) has always worked reliably for me.  In any case, here is the function I use to enable/disable blocking on a socket:

```
#include <fcntl.h>

/** Returns true on success, or false if there was an error */
bool SetSocketBlockingEnabled(int fd, bool blocking)
{
   if (fd < 0) return false;

#ifdef _WIN32
   unsigned long mode = blocking ? 0 : 1;
   return (ioctlsocket(fd, FIONBIO, &mode) == 0);
#else
   int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
   if (flags == -1) return false;
   flags = blocking ? (flags & ~O_NONBLOCK) : (flags | O_NONBLOCK);
   return (fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags) == 0);
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 63):

You're misinformed about `fcntl()` not always being reliable.  It's untrue.

To mark a socket as non-blocking the code is as simple as:

```
// where socketfd is the socket you want to make non-blocking
int status = fcntl(socketfd, F_SETFL, fcntl(socketfd, F_GETFL, 0) | O_NONBLOCK);

if (status == -1){
  perror("calling fcntl");
  // handle the error.  By the way, I've never seen fcntl fail in this way
}
```

Under Linux, on kernels > 2.6.27 you can also create sockets non-blocking from the outset using [`socket()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html#DESCRIPTION) and [`accept4()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/accept4).

e.g.

```
   // client side
   int socketfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0);

   // server side - see man page for accept4 under linux 
   int socketfd = accept4( ... , SOCK_NONBLOCK);
```

It saves a little bit of work, but is less portable so I tend to set it with `fcntl()`.

Comment: Isn't it possible that your internal `fcntl` fails before the external `fcntl` fails?

Comment: depending on how you write your code you can possibly setup race conditions if you call `fcntl` after you've created the socket....that's why the `SOCK_NONBLOCK` flag was added, so you can atomically create a socket as non blocking

Comment: Beware that `fcntl(socketfd, F_GETFL, 0)` can fail, so check the return value before passing it into the output

Comment: F_GETFL doesn't require any arguments, consult the manpage.

Answer (score 16):

`fcntl()` or `ioctl()` are used to set the properties for file streams. When you use this function to make a socket non-blocking, function like `accept()`, `recv()` and etc, which are blocking in nature will return error and `errno` would be set to `EWOULDBLOCK`. You can poll file descriptor sets to poll on sockets.

Comment: Is there any other way of converting  a TCPIP to NON BLOCKING socket. I dont want to rely on these methods may be because of my past experiences

Comment: That **is** the way to convert a socket to non-blocking. If you can be specific on your "past experiences" and why you are convinced that this won't work, maybe we can help you.

Comment: You can pass `SOCK_NONBLOCK` to the `socket` call.

Answer (score 10):

On Linux and BSD you can directly create the socket in non-blocking mode (https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html):

```c
int fd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype | SOCK_NONBLOCK | SOCK_CLOEXEC, res->ai_protocol);
if (fd == -1) {
    perror("socket");
    return -1;
}
```

When accepting connections you can use the `accept4` function to directly accept new connections in non-blocking mode (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html):

```c
int fd = accept4(lfd, NULL, 0, SOCK_NONBLOCK | SOCK_CLOEXEC);
if (fd == -1) {
    perror("accept4");
    return -1;
}
```

I don't know why the accepted answer doesn't mention this.

Comment: accept4() is a nonstandard Linux extension.

Answer (score 5):

I know it's an old question, but for everyone on google ending up here looking for information on how to deal with blocking and non-blocking sockets here is an in depth explanation of the different ways how to deal with the I/O modes of sockets - http://dwise1.net/pgm/sockets/blocking.html.

Quick summary:

- **So Why do Sockets Block?**
- **What are the Basic Programming Techniques for Dealing with Blocking Sockets?**

  - **Have a design that doesn't care about blocking**
  - **Using select**
  - **Using non-blocking sockets.**
  - **Using multithreading or multitasking**

Comment: Nice find, very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to change **socket to non blocking** , precisely **accept()** to **NON-Blocking** state then

```
    int flags=fcntl(master_socket, F_GETFL);
        fcntl(master_socket, F_SETFL,flags| O_NONBLOCK); /* Change the socket into non-blocking state  F_SETFL is a command saying set flag and flag is 0_NONBLOCK     */                                          

while(1){
    if((newSocket = accept(master_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &address, &addr_size))<0){
                if(errno==EWOULDBLOCK){
                       puts("\n No clients currently available............ \n");
                       continue;
               }
    }else{
          puts("\nClient approched............ \n");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is sometimes convenient to employ the "send/recv" family of system calls. If the `flags` parameter contains the `MSG_DONTWAIT` flag, each call will behave similar to a socket having the `O_NONBLOCK` flag set.

```
ssize_t send(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags);

ssize_t recv(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags);
```

Comment: Sadly, this don't work on all types of files, makes it impossible to use it in a file agnostic library.

Answer (score 3):

Generally you can achieve the same effect by using normal **blocking IO** and **multiplexing** several IO operations using `select(2)`, `poll(2)` or some other system calls available on your system.

See [The C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) for the comparison of approaches to scalable IO multiplexing.

Comment: Not under POSIX, as `man select` states in BUG section, `select` can report socket to be ready for `read`, but then `read` may block. So it's not completely the same.

Comment: We've moved significantly beyond C10K problems now.

Comment: syscall poll(2) is O(n), epoll(2) is O(1) which is only solution to C10K+

Comment: or use kqueue if freebsd is an option

Answer (score 2):

The best method for setting a socket as non-blocking in C is to use ioctl.  An example where an accepted socket is set to non-blocking is following:

```
long on = 1L;
unsigned int len;
struct sockaddr_storage remoteAddress;
len = sizeof(remoteAddress);
int socket = accept(listenSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&remoteAddress, &len)
if (ioctl(socket, (int)FIONBIO, (char *)&on))
{
    printf("ioctl FIONBIO call failed\n");
}
```

Comment: Isn't it async socket rather than a non-blocking?

Comment: In C/C++, its actually non-blocking using standard sockets/winsock.