# In a non blocking socket connect, select() always returns 1

Tags: c, sockets, select, nonblocking

I have this code segment that is designed to connect to a server using a socket connection. However if it can not connect to the server within a certain amount of time I would like it to stop trying. I tried to do this with this nonblocking socket and the select command but select is always returning 1 indicating that the server exists when nothing exists at the address I give it. Any Ideas?

```
SOCKET tcp_client( char *hname, char *sname )  {    
    fd_set fdset;
    struct sockaddr_in peer;
    SOCKET s;
    FD_ZERO(&fdset);
    // FD_SET(STDIN, &fdset);
    FD_SET(s, &fdset);
    errno=1;
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 15;
    set_address( hname, sname, &peer, "tcp" );
    s = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );

    int n = 1;
    fcntl(s, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

    if ( !isvalidsock( s ) )
    {
        printf("Socket Call Failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return(0);
    }

    int x = 0;

    int status = connect( s, ( struct sockaddr * )&peer, sizeof( peer ) );

    if(status < 0) {
        printf("Status: %i\n", status); 
    }

    int retVal = select(s+1, &fdset, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    printf("retVal: %i\n", retVal);

    if (retVal == 1) {
        int so_error;
        socklen_t slen = sizeof so_error;
        getsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &so_error, &slen);
        if (so_error == 0) {
            printf("work\n");

            x =1;
        } else {
            printf("fail\n");
            x = 0;
        }
    } else {     
        printf("noSocks\n"); 
    }


    if (x ==0 )
    {
        printf("Connect Failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        L("libOnexc: Connect to socket failed");
        close(s);
        return(0);
    } 

    return s;
}
```

Comment: Please fix your indenting.  It's horrible!

Comment: Well I'm not waiting on it more of waiting for 15 seconds using select() to see if it has connected, but select is always returning that its connected when its not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One problem I see is that you stick s in the fdset before you have created the socket.  You need to do the

```
FD_SET(s, &fdset);
```

after you've created the socket because s is just an integer and so will not be the right value until after the call to socket().

**EDIT**

Like this:

```
.
.
.
SOCKET s;
errno=1;
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 15;
set_address( hname, sname, &peer, "tcp" );
s = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );

int n = 1;
fcntl(s, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

if ( !isvalidsock( s ) )
{
    printf("Socket Call Failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return(0);
}    

FD_ZERO(&fdset);
FD_SET(s, &fdset); // don't put socket in set until it is actually created
```

Comment: I moved it to after the socket is created but now select always returns 0 even when trying to connect to a machine I know exists...

Comment: `fcntl(s, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);` is incorrect. You overwrite other flags that may be set. Also see [How do I change a TCP socket to be non-blocking?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1543466/608639)

Answer (score 14):

You need to check whether the socket is ready for writing (the second `fd_set *` argument to select), not reading (the first one).

Comment: @Daniel Then give the guy a +1 ;-) I'll do it for you.