# BSD socket connect + select (client)

Tags: sockets, bsd

There must be something wrong in the below code but I don't seem to be able to use a client connect, non blocking in combination with a select statement. Please ignore the below lack of error handling.

I seem to have two issues
1. select blocks until timeout (60) if I try to connect port 80 on an internet server
2. trying to connect a existing or non existing port on 127.0.0.1 always instantly returns the select with no way to distinction between success or failure to connect.

What am I missing in my understanding of BSD nonblocking in combination with select?

```
fd_set readfds;
FD_ZERO(&readfds);

struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 60;
tv.tv_usec = 0;

struct sockaddr_in dest;
int socketFD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

memset(&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));
dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
dest.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
dest.sin_port = htons(9483);

long arg;
arg = fcntl(socketFD, F_GETFL, NULL);
arg |= O_NONBLOCK;
fcntl(socketFD, F_SETFL, arg);

if (connect(socketFD, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, sizeof(struct sockaddr))<0 && errno == EINPROGRESS) {

    //now add it to the read set
    FD_SET(socketFD, &readfds);
    int res = select(socketFD+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

    int error = errno;
    if (res>0 && FD_ISSET(socketFD, &readfds)) {
        NSLog(@"errno: %d", error); //Always 36
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`errno` is set in your original attempt to `connect` -- legitimately: that is, it's in-progress. You then call `select`. Since `select` *didn't* fail, `errno` is not being reset. System calls only set `errno` on failure; they do not clear it on success.

The `connect` may have completed successfully. You aren't checking that though. You should add a call to `getsockopt` with `SO_ERROR` to determine whether it worked. This will return the error state on the socket.

One other important note. According to the manual page (https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=connect&sektion=2), you should be using the `writefds` to await completion of the `connect`. I don't know whether the `readfds` will correctly report the status.

```
[EINPROGRESS]   The socket is non-blocking and the connection cannot
                be completed immediately.  It is possible to select(2)
                for completion by selecting the socket for writing.
```

See also this very similar question. [Using select() for non-blocking sockets to connect always returns 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11286094/1076479)

Comment: Excellent answer! Thanks Gil!