# select() returns 1 on not-connected socket (inconsistent)

Tags: c, linux, sockets, nonblocking

I am using non-blocking sockets to connect to a server.
In a specific test scenario, the server is down, which means a TCP SYN goes out, but there is no response and there can never be an established connection.

In this setup, usually `select` times out after 2 seconds returning 0.
This is the behavior most of the time and it seems correct.

However, in roughly 5% of the cases, `select` immediately returns 1 (indicating the socket is readable in the mask).
But when I `read(2)` from the socket, `-1` is returned with '`Network is unreachable`'

```
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
// sockfd checked and > 0
// set non-blocking

struct timeval tv{};
tv.tv_sec = 2;

int ret = connect(sockfd, addr, addrlen ); // addr set elsewhere
if (ret < 0 && errno == EINPROGRESS)
{
    fd_set cset;
    FD_ZERO(&cset);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &cset);
    
    ret = select(sockfd + 1, &cset, nullptr, nullptr, &tv);
    // returns 1 sometimes
}
```

In the first post, I incorrectly stated that in the error case, there is only one TCP SYN on the network (without retries).
This is not true; in both the error  and non-error case, there is a TCP SYN on the network that is re-sent after 1 second.

What might cause this and is there a way to get consistent behavior with `select` ?

Comment: it's set non-blocking, but I did not include it in the code (there's comment though)

Comment: [Does this address your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417821/non-blocking-socket-select-returns-1-after-connect)

Comment: [Similar here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5843852/645128) (also linked in above link)

Comment: @ryyker The question is related, but it's a different scenario. Apparently  TCP RST is returned which makes the socket readable.. In my case, there is no response from the network

Comment: Have you considered `select`ing for *writing* instead of reading? Does that change anything?

Comment: "there is no response from the network" how do you know? Have you snooped on the wire? All packets or just TCP?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.Yes, I ran a `tcpdump` with only the destination IP in the filter. TCP SYN going out and nothing else

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Just tried _writing_ instead of _reading_, the result is the same

Comment: The "network unreachable" reply doesn't come from the destination IP. It is unreachable!

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. well, it's not that it "comes" from anywhere other than [the kernel itself](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L238) though, doubt you'd see anything on the wire.

Comment: The first question ryyker refers to is about a client connecting to an IP with no port listening. That is when the server returns a TCP/RST which leads to the observed behavior in that question. In my case, the remote IP is non-existent

Comment: @MarcoBonelli You are likely to see an ICMP packet from the gateway, because your host probably doesn't do any routing.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. oh, so you're saying that the host receives a "Destination Unreachable" ICMP and that the kernel marks the socket as ready for I/O after seeing that? That's interesting...

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Yeah I think so, what would be other reasons?

Answer (score 4):

The *correct* way to determine if a non-blocking `connect()` is finished is to ask `select()` for *writability* not *readability*. This is clearly stated in the [`connect()` documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html):

> EINPROGRESS
> The socket is nonblocking and the connection cannot be completed immediately.  (UNIX domain sockets failed with `EAGAIN` instead.)  **It is possible to `select(2)` or `poll(2)` for completion by selecting the socket for writing**.  After `select(2)` indicates **writability**, use `getsockopt(2)` to read the `SO_ERROR` option at level `SOL_SOCKET` to determine whether `connect()` completed successfully (`SO_ERROR` is zero) or unsuccessfully (`SO_ERROR` is one of the usual error codes listed here, explaining the reason for the failure).

It is **undefined behavior** to use `select()`/`poll()` to test a socket for readability before you know the connection has actually been established first.

Try this instead:

```c
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
// sockfd checked and > 0
// set non-blocking

int ret = connect(sockfd, addr, addrlen); // addr set elsewhere
if (ret < 0)
{
    if (errno != EINPROGRESS)
    {
        close(sockfd);
        sockfd = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        fd_set cset;
        FD_ZERO(&cset);
        FD_SET(sockfd, &cset);
    
        struct timeval tv{};
        tv.tv_sec = 2;

        ret = select(sockfd + 1, nullptr, &cset, nullptr, &tv);
        if (ret <= 0)
        {
            close(sockfd);
            sockfd = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            int errCode = 0;
            socklen_t len = sizeof(errCode);
            getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &errCode, &len);

            if (errCode != 0)
            {
                close(sockfd);
                sockfd = -1;
            }
        }
    }
}

if (sockfd != -1)
{
    // use sockfd as needed (read(), etc) ...
    close(sockfd);
}
```

Comment: Well of course you can test for readability, it will just indicate readability (i.e. data received from the peer) rather than a successfully established connection.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code per your suggestions.. `getsockopt` still returns `network unreachable` in about 5% of the connection attempts. The strange thing is that even with that error, I can see the TCP SYN go out on the network. I can try `ppoll`, but if this is a message from the kernel, it may trigger the same behavior

Comment: @curiousguy12 I never said a "network unreachable" error wouldn't happen. But you can't be sure the error is available until the socket reports writability, not readability.