# How to avoid data race with `asio::ip::tcp::iostream`?

Tags: c++, multithreading, tcp, c++14, boost-asio

## My question

How do I avoid a data race when using two threads to send and receive over an `asio::ip::tcp::iostream`?

### Design

I am writing a program that uses an `asio::ip::tcp::iostream` for input and output.  The program accepts commands from the (remote) user over port 5555 and sends messages over that same TCP connection to the user.  Because these events (commands received from the user or messages sent to the user) occur asynchronously, I have separate transmit and receive threads.

In this toy version, the commands are "one", "two" and "quit".  Of course "quit" quits the program.  The other commands do nothing, and any unrecognized command causes the server to close the TCP connection.

The transmitted messages are simple serial-numbered messages that are are sent once per second.

In both this toy version and the real code I'm trying to write, the transmit and receive processes are both using blocking IO, so there doesn't appear to be a good way to use a `std::mutex` or other synchronization mechanism.  (In my attempts, one process would grab the mutex and then block, which isn't going to work for this.)

### Build and test

To build and test this, I'm using gcc version 7.2.1 and valgrind 3.13 on a 64-bit Linux machine.  Build:

```
g++ -DASIO_STANDALONE -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++14 concurrent.cpp -o concurrent -lpthread
```

To test, I run the server with this command:

```
valgrind --tool=helgrind --log-file=helgrind.txt ./concurrent
```

Then I use `telnet 127.0.0.1 5555` in another window to create a connection to the server.  What `helgrind` correctly points out is that there is a data race because both `runTx` and `runRx` are trying to access the same stream asynchronously:

> ==16188== Possible data race during read of size 1 at 0x1FFEFFF1CC by thread #1
>
> ==16188== Locks held: none
>
> ... many more lines elided

### concurrent.cpp

```
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>
#include <array>
#include <chrono>

class Console {
public:
    Console() :
        want_quit{false},
        want_reset{false}
    {}
    bool getQuitValue() const { return want_quit; }
    int run(std::istream *in, std::ostream *out);
    bool wantReset() const { return want_reset; }
private:
    int runTx(std::istream *in);
    int runRx(std::ostream *out);
    bool want_quit;
    bool want_reset;
};

int Console::runTx(std::istream *in) {
    static const std::array<std::string, 3> cmds{
        "quit", "one", "two", 
    };
    std::string command;
    while (!want_quit && !want_reset && *in >> command) {
        if (command == cmds.front()) {
            want_quit = true;
        }
        if (std::find(cmds.cbegin(), cmds.cend(), command) == cmds.cend()) {
            want_reset = true;
            std::cout << "unknown command [" << command << "]\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << command << '\n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int Console::runRx(std::ostream *out) {
    for (int i=0; !(want_reset || want_quit); ++i) {
        (*out) << "This is message number " << i << '\n';
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        out->flush();
    }
    return 0;
}

int Console::run(std::istream *in, std::ostream *out) {
    want_reset = false;
    std::thread t1{&Console::runRx, this, out};
    int status = runTx(in);
    t1.join();
    return status;
}

int main()
{
    Console con;
    asio::io_service ios;
    // IPv4 address, port 5555
    asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(ios, 
            asio::ip::tcp::endpoint{asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 5555});
    while (!con.getQuitValue()) {
        asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream;
        acceptor.accept(*stream.rdbuf());
        con.run(&stream, &stream);
        if (con.wantReset()) {
            std::cout << "resetting\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be a [Producer - Consumer pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728068.aspx). Several different solutions are available, some without the explicit use of semaphores or the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you're sharing the socket that underlies the stream, without synchronization

> Sidenote, same with the boolean flags, which can easily be "fixed" by changing:
>
> ```
> std::atomic_bool want_quit;
> std::atomic_bool want_reset;
> ```

### How To Solve

To be honest, I don't think there is a good solution. You said it yourself: the operations are asynchronous, so you'll be in trouble if you try to do them synchronously.

You could try to think of hacks. What if we created a separate stream object based on the same underlying socket (filedescriptor). It's not going to be *very* easy as such a stream is not part of Asio.

But we could hack one up using Boost Iostreams:

```
#define BOOST_IOSTREAMS_USE_DEPRECATED
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file_descriptor.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

// .... later:

    // HACK: procure a _separate `ostream` to prevent the race, using the same fd
    namespace bio = boost::iostreams;
    bio::file_descriptor_sink fds(stream.rdbuf()->native_handle(), false); // close_on_exit flag is deprecated
    bio::stream<bio::file_descriptor_sink> hack_ostream(fds);

    con.run(stream, hack_ostream);
```

Indeed this runs without the race (simultaneous reads and writes on the same socket [are *fine*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021796/simultaneously-read-and-write-on-the-same-socket-in-c-or-c), as long as you don't share the non-threadsafe Asio  object(s) wrapping them).

### What I Recommend Instead:

**Don't do that**. It's a kludge. You're complicating things, apparently in an attempt to avoid using asynchronous code. I'd bite the bullet.

It's not too much work to factor the IO mechanics out from the service logic. You'll end up being free from random limitations (you could consider dealing with multiple clients, you could do without any threading *at all* etc.).

If you would like to learn about some middle ground, look at stackful coroutines (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/spawn.html)

### Listing

Just for reference

> Note I refactored to remove the need for pointers. You're not transferring ownership, so a reference will do. In case you didn't know how to pass the reference to a `bind`/`std::thread` constructor, the trick is in the `std::ref` you'll see.
>
> [For stress testing I have greatly reduced the delays.]

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbf301771dd7de97)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>
#include <array>
#include <chrono>

class Console {
public:
    Console() :
        want_quit{false},
        want_reset{false}
    {}
    bool getQuitValue() const { return want_quit; }
    int run(std::istream &in, std::ostream &out);
    bool wantReset() const { return want_reset; }
private:
    int runTx(std::istream &in);
    int runRx(std::ostream &out);
    std::atomic_bool want_quit;
    std::atomic_bool want_reset;
};

int Console::runTx(std::istream &in) {
    static const std::array<std::string, 3> cmds{
        {"quit", "one", "two"}, 
    };
    std::string command;
    while (!want_quit && !want_reset && in >> command) {
        if (command == cmds.front()) {
            want_quit = true;
        }
        if (std::find(cmds.cbegin(), cmds.cend(), command) == cmds.cend()) {
            want_reset = true;
            std::cout << "unknown command [" << command << "]\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << command << '\n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int Console::runRx(std::ostream &out) {
    for (int i=0; !(want_reset || want_quit); ++i) {
        out << "This is message number " << i << '\n';
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
        out.flush();
    }
    return 0;
}

int Console::run(std::istream &in, std::ostream &out) {
    want_reset = false;
    std::thread t1{&Console::runRx, this, std::ref(out)};
    int status = runTx(in);
    t1.join();
    return status;
}

#define BOOST_IOSTREAMS_USE_DEPRECATED
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file_descriptor.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

int main()
{
    Console con;
    boost::asio::io_service ios;

    // IPv4 address, port 5555
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(ios, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint{boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 5555});

    while (!con.getQuitValue()) {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream;
        acceptor.accept(*stream.rdbuf());

        {
            // HACK: procure a _separate `ostream` to prevent the race, using the same fd
            namespace bio = boost::iostreams;
            bio::file_descriptor_sink fds(stream.rdbuf()->native_handle(), false); // close_on_exit flag is deprecated
            bio::stream<bio::file_descriptor_sink> hack_ostream(fds);

            con.run(stream, hack_ostream);
        }

        if (con.wantReset()) {
            std::cout << "resetting\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
netcat localhost 5555 <<<quit
This is message number 0
This is message number 1
This is message number 2
```

And

```
commands=( one two one two one two one two one two one two one two three )
while sleep 0.1; do echo ${commands[$(($RANDOM%${#commands}))]}; done | (while netcat localhost 5555; do sleep 1; done)
```

runs indefinitely, occasionally resetting the connection (when command "three" has been sent).

Comment: "*It's not too much work to factor the IO mechanics out from the service logic.*" I don't understand what you mean or how to do that.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: Sure. In your code, don't tie the request loop to the `istream`, but instead make it receive request messages from "wherever" (interpose the [simplest interface you could think of](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26336487/)) and then you're free to replace the IO implementation with something asynchronous without "fearing" the complexity increase. It's hidden and compartmentalized.

Comment: OK, separating iO from processing makes sense, but I don’t know what you mean by “asynchronous code” in this context. This was my attempt at asynchronous code - no doubt there’s a better way to do it, but how?

Comment: @Edward You are painfully aware of the fact that nothing about your code is concurrent, but not asynchronous. This is manifest in the fact that IO operations block. Asynchronous IO is the bane of Asio, and you get it by using the `async_*` versions of calls. [It also means you will not be able to use the iostream abstraction, though you _can_ use `std::[io]stream` with `boost::asio::streambuf` still]

Comment: Ok, I guess I will go back to the asio docs try again to understand them. Apparently I’m still missing something fundamental but don’t know what it is. Still, I appreciate your time.