# boost asio stream_descriptor and event fd thread safety

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

`eventfd` is *thread safe* according to the [man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) *ATTRIBUTES* section

> ATTRIBUTES         top
>          For an explanation of the terms used in this section, see
>          attributes(7).
>
> ```
>    ┌──────────┬───────────────┬─────────┐
>    │Interface │ Attribute     │ Value   │
>    ├──────────┼───────────────┼─────────┤
>    │eventfd() │ Thread safety │ MT-Safe │
> ```

I want to wrap `eventfd` with `boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor` so I will be able to use it in *boost::asio::io_service*.

According to `boost stream_descriptor` [reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/posix__stream_descriptor.html), `stream_descriptor` isn't *thread safe*

> Thread Safety
>   Distinct objects: Safe.
>   Shared objects: Unsafe.

So if I understand correctly it's not safe to read / write using `boost::asio`'s `async_read_some` / `write_some` with multiple threads from / to an `eventfd` wrapped with `stream_descriptor`.

Which is kind of a "downgrade", because native `eventfd` allows it.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed.

---

Some precisions:

- The threadsafety applies to the `eventfd` call, not the fd
- Regardless, fd's are threadsafe and you can do syscalls on them freely
- It's not a "downgrade" of course because you can still use the fd in the same way as before (nobody forces you to use a non-threadsafe object)

Nothing is stopping you from creating two instances tied to the same fd.
Just use `release()` to avoid (double) close.

A similar/related answer here: [How to avoid data race with `asio::ip::tcp::iostream`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48117493/how-to-avoid-data-race-with-asioiptcpiostream/48123713#48123713)

Comment: "It's not a "downgrade" of course because you can still use the fd in the same way as before (nobody forces you to use a non-threadsafe object)" - you mean, using the native `eventfd` + syscalls `read()`, `write()` ?

Comment: "Nothing is stopping you from creating two instances tied to the same fd" - I would my implementation to support N threads

Comment: What are you using the eventfd for? It seems to me you choose to do scheduling outside of Asio. (Why are you trying to fit it in? If you want to, why not move all the responsibility to Asio)

Comment: I think I'm missing something :/ . I'm trying to use `eventfd` - so I'll have an asio thread who `async_read_some()` on this `eventfd`, and do some functionality when receives these events. While other threads may send events on the same `eventfd`. These other threads doesn't share the same `io_service`, they might even not be asio threads. I'm calling `asio thread` for threads who invoked `io_service::run()`

Comment: Then logically I wouldn't expect many threads to run an io_service. Just create an instance of the asio steam descriptor wrapper per thread. Really I think I'd separate io and execution if this would be "many" threads

Comment: What do you mean by "separate io and execution" ?
I also read it in the link you attached, in your answer, and didn't understand

Comment: It's usually not useful to do async IO on multiple threads. For exceptionally low-latency applications you can benefit from doing IO on as many threads as there are logical CPUs. More indicates that threads will have "fight" for the resources anyways. Usually (think 10k servers) you can handle IO and events on 1 thread that enqueues work on a thread pool that might be bigger (e.g. because they contain blocking operations and waiting for interprocess synchronization, so it makes sense to have more logical threads of execution than there are CPUs).

Comment: The work tasks post their results back or directly delegate IO tasks back to the IO thread(s). In this scenario, you'd have a very limited number of threads (typically, one) that even deals with the events (and other async operations). And the other threads do the work. That's why it's called separation of IO and execution.

Comment: i have used delayed-write to deal with lots of concurrent io - mark objects dirty all day long, then write them in timed bursts - sqlite is working great with this pattern, it has multi-op transactions.

Comment: @moodboom Thanks for your illustration. I think it's a little advanced for OP here, but it goes to show that separation of concerns is common-place and if you know where the latency/bottlenecks actually come from, doesn't need to cost a thing (keeping complexity down is always a win)

Comment: @sehe yep, scratching out data onto a platter is expensive!  :-)