# Does Boost asio ip tcp iostream support asynch?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio

I am coding network stuff via tcp/ip.

Specifically I have been using boost::asio.

Recently, to ease coding, I started using `boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream`.
It can be useful for fast developing! But I am not sure whether it uses `async_read` or `async_write`.

Does anybody know whether it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it cannot. That's most of what makes it so simple.

However, you **can** force a full-duplex experience using `boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream` with some tweaks. You'll need to run the reading/writing tasks on separate threads to achieve the parallellism without having asynchrony.

An examples of this - what I consider to be a - hack, is here:

[How to avoid data race with `asio::ip::tcp::iostream`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48117493/how-to-avoid-data-race-with-asioiptcpiostream/48123713#48123713)

That answer does *also* give the asynchronous approach, so that may help remove the intimidation factor because you can simply compare side-by-side both approaches.

Comment: Great! Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. Please consider reading https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: sorry for forgetting to select the best answer. Done :-)