# Can two threads share boost::asio tcp socket for exclusively reading and writing?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, boost, boost-asio

This question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1981372/1398841) asked about POSIX threads, but I would like to know what the answer is for `boost::asio` [`ip::tcp::socket`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html):

> 1. Can we call send from one thread and recv from another on the same socket?

In a C++11 application I'd like to share a `tcp::socket` such that one thread does blocking [`socket.read_some()`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/read_some/overload1.html) and processes incoming data and another thread shares the same `tcp::socket` and only performs [`boost::asio::write`()](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/write.html) calls. Will this be thread-safe?

Comment: As it stated in Asio documentation, 'socket' object is not thread-safe.

Comment: Slightly related, but more complicated: [sync tcp::iostream in a multi-threaded context has the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48117493/how-to-avoid-data-race-with-asioiptcpiostream/48123713#48123713). There's no way to "thread synchronize" your way out of that, so I came up with a hack based on **not sharing** the the `socket` object. Perhaps when you've read the docs, this example will help you solidify your understanding.