# cannot look at specific char returned by recv

Tags: c, websocket, webclient, recv

I need to read in only the values of a header that terminate with `\r\n\r\n`

Something like `GETFILE OK 1024\r\n\r\n <content>`

I'm trying to get the first `\r\n` and then get the next pair in a subsequent recv call. 
The call to this function is: `read_in_header(gfr, headerRecvBuff, 1);`

Issue: The logic in the while referring to `\n` is completely ignored, or does not show any matches, when I know they exist. Is this the right way to compare the char newline?

```
int read_in_header(gfcrequest_t *gfr, char *buf, int len) {
char *s = buf;
int slen = len;
int c = 0;
int count = 0;
//get the first \r\n pair
do {
    c = recv(gfr->client_fd, s, slen, 0);
    printf("checking to see what s has now: %s\n", s);
    count += c;
} while ((c > 0) && (s[count - 1] != '\n'));

//get the second \r\n pair
count = 0;
do {
    c = recv(gfr->client_fd, s, slen, 0);
    printf("checking to see what s has now: %s\n", s);
    count += c;
} while ((c > 0) && (s[count - 1] != '\n'));

printf("checking to see what s has now: %s\n", s);


if (c < 0) {
    return c;
} else if (c == 0) {
    puts("Time to disconnect, the server is done.");
    //total bytes received should not include header length
    gfr->totalbytesReceived -= gfr->headerbytes_received;
    return 0;
} else {
    s[c - 1] = '\0';
}
gfr->totalbytesReceived += count;
return c;
}
```

Comment: If the data is sent as a TCP stream, you can not rely on boundaries between data sent.  It's a **stream**.  If you try to receive 10 bytes, you may get 2 - or there may be 2000 bytes waiting for you to read.

Comment: Fyi, you're always reading data into the beginning of the memory addressed by `buf`. (aka `s` in this code). But `s[count-1]` uses an *accumulated* counter, not the number of octets read on the last `recv` call. In short, on a successful `recv` where `c > 0` the data read will be in `s[0..c-1]`. I don't see why you're using `count` to subscript `s`.

Comment: Yes, at first I thought recv would append to the buffer, but missed that s would be a pointer to the start of the buffer each time. I decided to use a combination of what you said and the logic from @ryyker

Answer (score 1):

Regarding *Is this the right way to compare the char newline?*

Since s is a buffer (not a single char), for the first loop the comparison method can be changed to

```
while ((c > 0) && (strstr(s, "\r\n") == NULL));
```

To require both "\r" & "\n" are there. This takes advantage of string searching to check both values are present in one line.

resulting in:

```
do {
    c = recv(gfr->client_fd, s, slen, 0);
    printf("checking to see what s has now: %s\n", s);
    //  count += c; //not needed
} while ((c > 0) && (strstr(s, "\r\n") == NULL));
```

If you decided to capture the line that has all 4, i.e. `\r\n\r\n`, then make that the argument of the comparison.

One side note, unless you have set socket options to non-blocking, recv() is a blocking call.  Look into ***[how to set a socket to non-blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543466/how-do-i-change-a-tcp-socket-to-be-non-blocking)***

Comment: I had length to be read in as 1 byte as well, but understood that on each iteration, the buffer would be overridden. I added non-blocking to the client file descriptor socket(client_fd) on creation, and i'm using the condition in your loop, but just with "\r\n\r\n" as per our protocol.